# Validation of a Data Flow Dependent on a Created Table in an SSIS Package

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have a SSIS package that I saved using the import wizard in SSMS.  The import uses a table to hold all of the values imported from a flat file before exporting those values into a permanent table.  For example, the flat file itself is imported into 'mytable'.  The contents of 'mytable' are then transferred to 'mypermanenttable'.  I recently added a drop mytable SQL statement to the end of the SSIS package.  Since I am now missing 'mytable' when I run the SSIS package again, I added a T-SQL statement to before the 'Preparation SQL Task 1' step in Control Flow that would create 'mytable' before the import begins.  I get an error when I try running the entire SSIS package.  I can however run every step of the SSIS process one by one and complete the entire package without any problems this way.  I am guessing there is some validation in the 'Preparation SQL Task 1' step that checks for 'mytable' before my create table 'Execute T-SQL Statement Task' runs.  How would you fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `DelayValidation` property of `Data Flow Task 1` to `True`. Validation will be fired just before running this task, after creation of your staging table.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try updating the SQL Task to include a check if the table exists:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
             AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
BEGIN
  --Create table
END
```